# How to disable SSMS table designer timeout?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

How do I disable the Table Designer timeout in SQL Server Management Studio?

## Background

[This KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915849) seems to indicate that if you stop *overriding* the **Designer** timeout:

> To resolve this behavior, use one of the following methods:
>
> - Click to clear the **Override connection string time-out value for table designer updates** check box for the table designer and for the database designer in SQL Server Management Studio.

[image]

it is supposed to revert to the **Execution** timeout:

[image]

But rather than timing out *never* it times out after 30 seconds:

[image]

I've also tried setting the table designer to the *maximum* value of `65,535`. Unfortunately that just causes the timeout to happen after 18 hours, rather than 30 seconds.

How do I **disable** the table designer timeout in SQL Server Management Studio?

SQL Server Management Studio: `9.00.1399.00`

Pre-emptive snarky comment: what kind of table change are you making that needs more than 18 hours to complete? I'm changing a column in a 130 GB table from `text` to `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: Well, why do you do it - FROM THE DESIGNER? Snarty comment - make it in a empty database, generate the change script and execute that in management studio. I regularly reformat 200+gb tables (though that just takes a couple of hours) and I would not DREAM of touching the designer for life data. I use a command line driven schema update mechanism that executes the change scripts deposited in it's folder structure. WAY too risky to do stuff like that manually without testing it first.

Comment: @TomTom The change script can lead to data loss; with all those `GO` statements (e.g. the `EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_Transactions` fails, and then proceeds to drop the original with `DROP TABLE dbo.Transactions`. i've only lost data once by manually running the generated scripts; i don't want that to happen again. That's why i prefer to do it from the designer, and not IN MANAGEMENT STUDIO. **Loud noises**. I DON'T KNOW WHAT WE'RE YELLING ABOUT.

Comment: Sorry? The change script manually tested will not. The change script run - as any sensible person would do - AFTER A BACKUP - would not. YOu do not like backups before starting database reorganizations?

Comment: @TomTom Of course it would be manually tested; but that doesn't handle the unforseen problem (e.g. random gamma ray from space causes SQL Server to abort the batch with a assertion failure - who the hell knows; it's unforseen). i *do* like backups before starting database reorganizations. Well, that's not true. i *don't* like that i need that safety net. i would prefer the database changes are guaranteed to succeed, without any need for a backup. The larger issue is that because of the use of `GO`, the scripts generated by SSMS are fundamentally unsafe to run. They are only a starting point.

Comment: Ah, I do not generate them by GO. I use Visual studio - which also holds the schema and generates the change script - and then manually fix up and separate it into a set of change scripts. SADLY there is no support for proper versioning of the database anywhere in the toolset....

Comment: Despite your comments above, I wouldn't do it in the designer. Your faith in it is somewhat unfounded. If you **must** use the designer then you can click the "script" icon in the toolbar to generate the code then sanity check it and run it in a new query window with no timeout problems.

Comment: Looking at your comments in more detail you are aware that transactions can span across GO statements? Also your stated goal can be done without rebuilding the table anyway. `ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn VARCHAR(MAX) [NOT] NULL`

Comment: @MartinSmith Are you aware that *some* kinds of errors will implicitly rollback the transaction, while other kinds of errors will leave it running? That's the cause of the data loss. The transaction you thought you were using got rolled back; then you proceed with the next batch - no longer in a transaction. **Nitpicker's Corner**: Don't confuse the example with the question.

Comment: @IanBoyd - Ah right I see the issue. In that case you can enable `sqlcmd` mode on the Query menu and add `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` and `:on error exit` to the top of the script;

Answer (score 1):

"...i'm changing a column in a 130 GB table from text to nvarchar(max)..."

Hi If you change a column and you expect that it can take considerable amount of time - I would recommend writing a Query.

Depending on you situation it could be as simple as "ALTER COLUMN" or as complex as "Creating temp table, coping all data, dropping table, creating table with new structure, copying data from temp table".

In any situation, having a script will allow you to run it without any timeout probably in you maintenance window (if you have one).

Regards,